# Counting the number of times my android app opens and handling screen orientation

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-orientation

In detail, I am counting the number of times my app opens with the help of the interface `SharedPreferences` and showing that count on screen but when ever I change `orientation` the count still increments.

I do not want to stick the layout in portrait, I want both orientations available for my app the code for the `onCreate()` is shown below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate!");

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    int count = mPrefs.getInt(COUNT, 0);

    count = count + 1;
    Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(COUNT, count);
    editor.commit();

    mTextView = new TextView(this);
    mTextView.setTextSize(40);
    mTextView.setText("Count: " + count);
    Log.d(TAG, "Count is " + count);
    setContentView(mTextView);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could only increment the count when it hasn't been saved via `savedInstanceState` because `onSaveInstaceState` is called when the orientation is changed

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY)){
            count = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY);
        } 
    } else {
        count = mPrefs.getInt(COUNT, 0);
        count += 1;
        Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(COUNT, count);
        editor.commit();
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(KEY, count);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OnCreate is called whenever the devices orientation changes. Try putting the relevant code in OnStart instead.